Using SwiftData how does one sync a public database?
I have an iOS project with CloudKit, Background, and Remote Notifications enabled.
I have specified an @Model type that matches the name of the record in the CloudKit database.
But when I created the @Query variable in no data is synced.
Looking at the ModelConfiguration init overloads, there's one that takes a cloudKitDatabase argument which has options of 'none', 'automatic', and 'private'. Which makes me think that public might not be possible.
Otherwise, I can't find any information on how to do this.

According to this article from Paul Hudson it’s not possible to use a public database with SwiftData
